# DirectX framework performance issue

Tags: c++, performance, directx, directx-9

After continuously capture mouse input ie. left and right click, the pc will become very lag when switching to another software such as Google Chrome but when you end the framework for few seconds will back to normal with no lag.

The framework works fine until I create Graphics object. So, I doubt there is something wrong with Graphics class but I still cannot find out which part cause this performance issue.

Graphics class

Graphics.h

```
#ifndef GRAPHICS_H
#define GRAPHICS_H

#include <d3d9.h>

class Graphics
{
public:
    Graphics();
    ~Graphics();
    void initialize(HWND hWnd, int backBufferWidth, int backBufferHeight);
    void BeginFrame();
    void EndFrame();

private:
    IDirect3D9*       direct3D9;
    IDirect3DDevice9* d3dDevice;
};

#endif
```

Graphics.cpp

```
#include "Graphics.h"

Graphics::Graphics()
{
}

Graphics::~Graphics()
{
    //  Release the device when exiting.
    d3dDevice->Release();
    //  Reset pointer to NULL.
    d3dDevice = NULL;
}

void Graphics::initialize(HWND hWnd, int backBufferWidth, int backBufferHeight)
{
    //  Define Direct3D 9.
    direct3D9 = Direct3DCreate9(D3D_SDK_VERSION);

    //  Define how the screen presents.
    D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS d3dPP;
    ZeroMemory(&d3dPP, sizeof(d3dPP));

    d3dPP.Windowed           = true;
    d3dPP.SwapEffect         = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;
    d3dPP.BackBufferFormat   = D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8;
    d3dPP.BackBufferCount    = 1;
    d3dPP.BackBufferWidth    = backBufferWidth;
    d3dPP.BackBufferHeight   = backBufferHeight;
    d3dPP.hDeviceWindow      = hWnd;

    //  Create a Direct3D 9 device.
    direct3D9->CreateDevice(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, D3DDEVTYPE_HAL, hWnd, 
    D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING, &d3dPP, &d3dDevice);
}

void Graphics::BeginFrame()
{
    //  Clear the back buffer.
    d3dDevice->Clear(0, NULL, D3DCLEAR_TARGET, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 0, 0), 1.0f, 0);

    //  Begin the scene
    d3dDevice->BeginScene();
}

void Graphics::EndFrame()
{
    //  End the scene
    d3dDevice->EndScene();

    //  Present the back buffer to screen
    d3dDevice->Present(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
}
```

Here is my whole project if you want to check all the codes : https://www.dropbox.com/s/p4nm57fzqse12t7/Zero%20DirectX%20Framework.rar

Comment: GraphicsClass has been instanced in your compiled example? I have found no errors in the code which placed here, except that you did not check for `D3DCREATE_HARDWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING`. Please tell me the model of your CPU.

Comment: Yes. My CPU is Intel Core i7 3610QM but I think it's not the issue because before that I apply the same things in procedural approach but after I change to object-oriented approach as above, the issue comes out.

Comment: Use the task manager to observe the CPU and memory usage of your app when the computer becomes slow. I suspect heavy disk, CPU, or memory usage.

Comment: Ya. The framework uses a lot of CPU and desktop windows manager increases gradually too.  http://i.stack.imgur.com/O5C2t.png

Comment: Can you post the code on how to use this class? or upload a .zip file instead of rar file?

Comment: Sure. Here it's. https://www.dropbox.com/s/9g5yv9rxpniy0fy/Zero%20DirectX%20Framework.zip

Comment: Use profiler to check where CPU spend most time.

Comment: `D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING` is possibly a clue?